# Azure Redirect URI showing directory path

Tags: azure-active-directory, visual-studio-2019

I Created web application using azure authentication. I created app registration with secrets key.
Its working fine while debugging but After publish the project in localhost its won't working. its showing folder dir path only.

**My Code**

```
              if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                   
                    Response.Redirect("default.aspx",false);
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new 
                    AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
                    
                }
```

**Web Config**

```
<add key="ida:GraphResourceId" value="https://graph.microsoft.com" />
<add key="ida:GraphUserUrl" value="https://graph.microsoft.com/{0}/me?api-version=2013-11-08" />
<add key="todo:TodoListResourceid" value="api://xxxxxxxxxxx" />
<add key="todo:TodoListBaseAddress" value="http://localhost/Test/" />
<add key="ida:ClientId" value="xxxxxxx" />
<add key="ida:AppKey" value="xxxxxxxxx" />
<add key="ida:Tenant" value="aaaaaaaaaaa" />
<add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}" />
<add key="ida:RedirectUri" value="http://localhost/Test" />
```

Error Image :
[image: After Publish showing like this]

Comment: Have you added redirect url as 'http://localhost/Test' in azure ad app -> authentication ->Web ?

Comment: @Tiny-wa Yes....

Comment: I'm not familiar with your code, and I found a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp#option-2-register-and-manually-configure-your-application-and-code-sample), it worked for me. If it doesn't meet your requirement, maybe you can offer more details on how you start your project such as which sample you're referring to.

Comment: @Tiny-wa its working fine while debugging from vs 2017 . After publish to iis it will show like this.

Comment: Oh, but I don't know about IIS, Sorry. But I guess it may relate to 'localhost', your local environment may be different with IIS.